# How to make a user input into variable name?

Tags: javascript, object, variables, input

I need help with a specific piece of code. It is kind of difficult to describe, but I'll try to do it the best I can. I need to check a specific attribute of an object based on user input. For example, if the user inputs 'London', I want to be able to access an attribute called 'xcoor.london'.

Before I have tried a lot of 'if' and 'else if', for example,

```
xcoordinate = xcoor.london;
ycoordinate = ycoor.london;
}else if(input == 'Paris'){
xcoordinate = xcoor.paris;
ycoordinate = ycoor.paris;
}else if(input == 'Washington D.C.'){
xcoordinate = xcoor.washdc;
ycoordinate = ycoor.washdc;
}
"But I have dozens of inputs and this takes a lot of code. 
I am just revising this program to make it take up less space, 
and this part is the major problem.
I want something like this:"
var xcoor = {
london: 0.1278,
paris: 2.3522,
...
}
var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
xcoordinate = xcoor.input;
```

That's pretty much all; any ideas are welcome and appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `xcoordinate = xcoor[input];`

Answer (score 1):

I would make a dictionary for the coordinates. Like this:

```js
const coordinates = {
"London": {x: ..., y: ...},
"Paris": {x: ..., y: ...}
};

console.log('The coordinates for London: ',coordinates['London']);
console.log('The x coordinate for Paris: ', coordinates['Paris'].x);
```

If you want to use your `input` var to find the coordinates, you can do it like this:

```js
const result = coordinates[input];
console.log(result.x, result.y) //returns the x and y coordinates for the user input
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
xcoordinate = xcoor[input.toLowerCase()];
```

With a map object, it will save alot of if else

```
var map = {
     'washington d.c.': 'washdc',
     'las vegas': 'lasvegas'
};
var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
xcoordinate = xcoor[map[input.toLowerCase()] || input.toLowerCase()];
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work out of the box as "Washington D.C." should be stored  in `xcor["washdc"]` not in `xcor["washington d.c."]`, so you will need some kind of mapping.

Comment: Yes, he will need a map object anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to solve it using the object as shown below,

```
var xcolor = {
london: 0.1278,
paris: 2.3522,
// keep adding more values here 

}

var ycolor = {
    london: 0.9,
    paris : 10
    // keep adding more values here 
}

let  coordinates = {
    xcoordinate : undefined,
    ycoordinate : undefined 
}



function setInput(input){

  if(xcolor.hasOwnProperty(input) && ycolor.hasOwnProperty(input)){
    coordinates.xcoordinate = xcolor[input];
    coordinates.ycoordinate = ycolor[input];
  }
}

setInput('paris');

console.log(coordinates.xcoordinate);
console.log(coordinates.ycoordinate);

setInput('london');
console.log(coordinates.xcoordinate);
console.log(coordinates.ycoordinate);
```

I hope it helps